# Importing 3ds Max OBJ using C++

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I have created a an OBJ loader that can import .OBJ files that were exported from 3DS Max into my simple OpenGL viewer / app. At the heart of this was a Vector3.h written with the help of some tutorials.

It worked great on a couple models I used, but the one I want to work with has something different that wasn't accounted for. It has 4 points in its vertices instead of 3. Here is a sample of a line I am working with:

```
g Box02
usemtl Wood_Bark
s 4
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/2
f 4/1/3 3/2/3 5/3/3
```

The first 'f' line has 4 vertices I am interested in. My Vertex3.h takes X, Y, Z. In the other models I had, all lines were like the second 'f' line, with only 3 elements. I am getting a vertex out of range, so when I went to check where it was happening, I saw it was on this line, so I assumed because there is more data on the line that can be handled. Here is the entire Vertex3.h

http://pastebin.com/dgGSBSFe

And this is the line of code that fails. vertices is a Vector3.

```
tempVertices.push_back ( vertices[--vertex] );
```

My question is, what is the 4th point? How would you account for that in something like my Vector3.h file? Seems like I need to create a Vector4.h, and ignore the 4th var if there is only 3 on the line. But I would like to know more about what I am dealing with, and any tips on how to do it. Is the 4th element an alpha or something? How should it be used, or should it be used at all in my calculations in Vector3.h?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A face with four points is called a quad. Usually if you want to render it you should break it up into two triangles.

So for example, you have this:

```
 ___
|   |
|   |
|___|
```

You need to turn it into this:

```
 ___
|\  |
| \ |
|__\|
```

Assuming the vertices go counter-clockwise (the default in OpenGL), starting from the upper left, you could make two triangles. The first triangle's vertices would be the quad's first, second, and third vertices. The second triangle's vertices would be the quad's third, fourth, and first vertices.

Comment: I was thinking that may be a problem, but this is a 3dsMax model that was created by someone else. I don't have the app or the skills to fix it. I may need to find someone who knows how to do that. Shoot, I thought I could fix it myself.

Comment: @Hallik: I'm not suggesting you change the model. I'm suggesting you make your code auto-split quads as it comes across them.

Comment: OK I will have to think through how to do that. I know I had read somewhere always break things up into triangles, But the face it also stores normals & UVWs on the same line as the vertices, has been throwing me off. Need to retrain my thinking. A lot of this is pretty new.

Comment: @Hallik: Just clone the normals and UVs the same way you'd clone the vertices.

Comment: Just came back to say, my quick fix was to export from 3ds max & force triangles during export.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you export as triangles only? Convert to EMesh in 3ds max, make all edges visible, export. Or simply use the appropriate OBJ export option.